# Hook into MobileMusicPlayer on iOS 4

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, jailbreak

How can I hook into MobileMusicPlayer with MobileSubstrate and theos. In every example I find I see `#import <MobileMusicPlayer/MobileMusicPlayer.h>` But from what I understand, the MobileMusicPlayer framework is no longer included in iOS 4. So what file do I include?

EDIT: I tried doing a class-dump of MobileMusicPlayer and output everything into a file which I named MobileMusicPlayer.h. Then I imported that into my Tweak.xm file. But compiling gave me lots of errors http://pastie.org/1765614

EDIT 2: I also tried doing a class-dump of MobileMusicPlayer and put all the files into a folder in the /usr/includes directory of my iOS SDK. But when I try to hook any of the classes in any of those files, nothing happens on the iPod itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, I feel stupid. I had `com.apple.spirngboard` set as a filter in my plist file which means that MobileSubstrate should only apply my tweak to SpringBoard.app. After changing that to `come.apple.mobileipod` it seems to work fine!